# How to activate snapping for layer you are drawing polygons in?

Tags: qgis, snapping

I want to draw multiple polygons in a layer that have boundaries without a gap, so I activated snapping for that layer. But it doesn't work. For other layers it works fine.

Comment: You need to add more detail. Show how you have snapping settings configured, what type of layer it is, what version of QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mark a tolerance or distance of snapping? If your layer is proyected only put the tolerance value for that layer.

I don't know but if you have a layer in [geographics coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system) (GPS 'raw' data like GPX, OSM...) the snapping distance might be 360degrees/40000km (aprox. Equator length) =9*10^-3 km or in meters 9*10^-6.

So you need to set to 0.00001 for about 1 meter snapping distance.

Multiply this number by the number of meters you need for snap.

[image]

I'm sorry but I have my QGIS in Spanish.

Answer (score 2):

I always use a tolerance of 10 **Pixel** for snapping.

This works independent from scale and zoom levels.